# Executing one thread at a time in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have a requirement where I want to execute a group of samplers in such a way that only one thread executes it at any given point of time.

Please let me know how can I do it?

Thanks

Comment: Show use what you done until now.

Comment: Stupid question: why not have only one thread that loops of the samplers?